# How to programmatically change default for the toggle button

Tags: android, android-button

I have a toggle button with the following drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_pressed"/> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart"/> 
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_pressed"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart"/> 
</selector>
```

This is working fine. However, since this is a favorite button when I present the screen second time and it contains some items that are favorite to begin with, I want to change the default from `heart` to `heart_pressed`

I tried doing it programmatically like this in `getView` of my `ArrayAdapter`, however, with this I lose the "toggle" capability of the button.

```
if (item.isFav())  
         holder.hButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_pressed));
else
         holder.hButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart));
```

**Question**

Is there a way to change the default of a ToggleButton programmatically based on a condition in the code?

Comment: Create two different drawables one for the pressed heart shape and one normal and in the else and if condition refer to the drawables. The drawables should be similar to the default toggle buttons drawable